# Energy momentum tensor of a scalar field by variation of metric

Tags: general-relativity, field-theory, variational-principle, functional-derivatives

For the scalar field $\phi$,
$$ L = \frac{1}{2}\left(\partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu \phi + m^2 \phi^2\right) $$
The energy momentum tensor calculated using noether's theorem is given by
$$ T^{\mu \nu} = \partial^\mu \phi \partial^\nu \phi - \eta^{\mu \nu}L $$

Im trying to calculate the same thing by varying the action for the field with respect to a general metric $g_{\mu \nu} $ using:

$$ T^{\mu \nu} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{-g}} \frac{\delta S}{\delta g_{\mu \nu}} $$
So,
$$\frac{\delta S}{\delta g_{\mu \nu}} = \frac{\delta}{\delta g_{\mu \nu}} \int d^4x \frac{\sqrt{-g}}{2}\left(g_{\mu \nu}\nabla^\mu\phi\nabla^\nu\phi + m^2 \phi^2\right)  \\ = \frac{\sqrt{-g}\nabla^\mu\phi\nabla^\nu\phi}{2} + \frac{\delta \sqrt{-g}}{g_{\mu \nu}} \frac{L}{2}$$

Now since $\delta \sqrt{-g} = \sqrt{-g} g^{\mu\nu} \delta g_{\mu\nu}/2 = -\sqrt{-g} g_{\mu\nu} \delta g^{\mu\nu}/2$, so we should have $ \frac{\delta\sqrt{-g}}{\delta g_{\mu\nu}} = \sqrt{-g} g^{\mu\nu}/2 $, which gives me:

$$ T^{\mu\nu} = \nabla^\mu\phi\nabla^\nu\phi + g^{\mu \nu}L $$

The sign of the second term is positive, so clearly I must have done something wrong. I tried rechecking the formula for the variation of $g$ but the seem to be correct. Please help me figure out where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You should vary  $L= g^{\mu\nu} \partial_\mu \phi \partial_\nu \phi$ with respect to the $g^{\mu\nu}$ metric rather  than.
$L= g_{\mu\nu} \partial ^\mu \phi \partial^\nu \phi$. This is  because $\partial^\mu=g^{\mu \nu}\partial _\nu$ secretly depends on the metric whilst $\partial_\mu\phi$ does not depend on the metric.

Be careful however as
$$
\delta S= \phantom -\frac 12\int  \delta g^{\mu\nu}(x) T_{\mu\nu}(x) \sqrt {g} d^dx, \nonumber\\
= -\frac 12  \int \delta g_{\mu\nu}(x) T^{\mu\nu}(x) \sqrt {g} d^dx. 
$$

The minus sign arises from  $\delta g^{\mu\nu }= - g^{\mu \alpha } (\delta  g_{\alpha\beta}) g^{\beta\nu}$.

Then $\delta \sqrt{g} =- \textstyle{\frac 12} \sqrt{g}g_{\mu\nu} \delta g^{\mu\nu}$, where I am using a Euclidean signature so I have $\sqrt{g}$ rather than $\sqrt{-g}$.

Comment: So, this is because in most conventions, the gradient is chosen to be naturally "lowered" or covariant?

Comment: @Albertus Magnus:  $\partial_\mu$   denotes the usual  $\partial/\partial x^\mu $ which  knows nothing of geometry. The same is not true of $g^{\nu\mu}\partial/\partial x^\mu $.

Comment: Could we not imagine a $\partial^\mu$ which knows nothing of geometry and then suppose that the same is not true for $g_{\mu\nu}{\partial\over\partial x_\mu}$?

Comment: @Albertus Magnus.  No. calculus is standard stuff. The derivative only cares about how the function $f(x)$ varies with $x$. It cares nothing about any notion of "distance" between $x$ and $x+dx$..

Comment: I see, thanks for indulging me.